# Ubuntu limiting my shared connection to 10mb/s

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, ethernet, connection

I am using a laptop to share internet to my pc, via lan cable. I have a 50mb/s line however the connection that I am getting on the pc is 10mb/s. the laptop itself is recording between 45-50mbps on speed tests. The same cable I plugged into another laptop of mine (MAC) to do the same thing the pc is now recording 50mbps. I dont want to be using the MAC for this job though.

***Summary***                 * ***Ubuntu 20.04****

Internet on pc limited to 10mbps
Lenovo wifi adapter doesnt seem to be a problem (recording 45-50 mbps on its end while connected)
Cable doesnt seem to be faulty as test with mac has pc at 50mbps

All done on the same WIFI network.

Comment: Some where there is a max 10 connection I guess you need to find it. Ubuntu is not doing this.

Comment: can you elaborate ? I currently am seeing no reason for it to be anything other than ubuntu.

Comment: What kind of cable some are maxed at 10mbs is it 5 5e 6 or 6e?

Comment: I am not sure as to the type of lan cable it is, Just a random one I got a while back, but I doubt its the cable. I used the same cable on the other laptop as a test to see if the cable was the issue. The pc was doing 49.7 mb/s, unfortunately I cannot use that specific laptop as a solution up until I to run cables through.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the speed of the connection in `nm-connection-editor`. Open the Ethernet connection and under the "Ethernet" tab, you can change "Link negotiation" to "Manual" and you can manually choose the speed of the connection.

Comment: I thought this would work but when I tried it, the internet service was ended. Really strange, I ended up doing some research on link negotiation saw that I needed to change the negotiation on both unfortunately not, 10 restarts and systemctl restarts later I unfortunately have the same problem.